# Transpose Matrix from python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, algorithm

I really don't understand the logic here.......

```
def transpose(A):
    output = [['']*len(A)] * len(A[0])
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        for i in range(len(A)):
            output[j][i] = A[i][j]
    return output
```

Input: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Expected Output: `[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]`

My Output: `[[3,6,9], [3,6,9], [3,6,9]]`

I know I can use zip to solve this problem easily, but I just want to know why this code will return duplicated lists.

New update, I have added some print to understand the process

```
def transpose(A):
    output = [['']*len(A)] * len(A[0])
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        for i in range(len(A)):
            output[j][i] = A[i][j]
            print(j)
            print(i)
            print(output)
    return output
```

And the outputs are:

```
0
0
[[1, '', ''], [1, '', ''], [1, '', '']]
0
1
[[1, 4, ''], [1, 4, ''], [1, 4, '']]
0
2
[[1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 7]]
1
0
[[2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 7]]
1
1
[[2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 7]]
1
2
[[2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 8]]
2
0
[[3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 8]]
2
1
[[3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 8]]
2
2
[[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]]
[[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]]
```

So, for example, the very first step of the loop. j = 0 and i = 0. However, output[0][0],output[1][0],and output[2][0] are all changed by the loop. Why is that??????

I am so confused right now. I have written the same code in Java and it runs properly.

```
public class TransposeMatrix {
    public static int[][] transpose(int[][] A) {
        int[][] result = new int[A[0].length][A.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < A[0].length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) result[j][i] = A[i][j];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The link of this problem is: https://leetcode.com/problems/transpose-matrix/

Comment: `transposed_matrix = list(map(list, zip(*input_matrix)))` input_matrix - list of lists; transposed_matrix - list of lists

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I know use zip is easy as I mentioned in the question. But my problem is that I am confused by the logic behind the code that I provided.

Comment: The `*` creates a number of references to the same list.

Comment: This is due to [['']*len(A)] consist of the same list ; so, when you change one nested list, all lists are changed. This is behavior of  multiplication `[]*N` and because lists are mutable in Python; Replace output with `[['' for k in A]] * len(A[0])`.

Comment: @KlausD. You are right! Thank you very much

Comment: @bubble one more question, since I have used ['']*len(A), why that did not change anything? Do you mean that * only affects nested lists?

Comment: Consider using `output = numpy.zeros((3,3))` to create your array, which gives you a 3x3 matrix will all 0 elements. Reference:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply lists in python like that, you don't actually create new lists but several references to the same list. Thus, when you change the value in one list, you also change it in the other lists. That's why your output is `[[3,6,9], [3,6,9], [3,6,9]]`; it's simply the last of the three lists (i.e. from the last value of the for loop).

Instead, you can do this:

```
def transpose(A):
    output = [['']* (len(A)) for y in range(len(A[0]))]
    # or: output = [['' for x in range(len(A))] for y in range(len(A[0]))]
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        for i in range(len(A)):
            output[j][i] = A[i][j]
    return output

transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

which returns `[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome! This has confused me often. Also, beware when you want to copy a list you need to use `.copy()` instead of simply `list1 = list2` since the latter only creates a reference (see [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/copy))